# React native ios app fails running with the message: reason: '-[RCTRootContentView reactTag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, react-native, unrecognized-selector

This is the error message I get when I try to deploy a react-native IOS app on my Iphone 5s:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTRootContentView reactTag]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance

There are no errors when I build the app, it appears only When I install it (hit the run button).

Any idea how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: The whole message is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTRootContentView reactTag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: you started project with react native or changed normal project to use react native?

Comment: started with react native. Turned off the dev mode and using the local main bundle instead of http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle

Comment: Also same happens on the simulator. Nothing special to the Iphone 5s device.

Comment: ok it seems that the reason was because the bundle (main.jsbundle) had errors. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the main.jsbundle I realized that it was almost empty, it has just a warning. After creating it correctly the error I mentioned above disappeared.